# Modular Shiny app workflow in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

While developing a modular Shiny app (with multiple .R files that are sourced by global.R) in RStudio I have to repeatedly

- switch to ui.R or server.R
- click Run App
- click Stop
- navigate back the R file I'm working on

Doing this many times is a pain as I hardly work on ui.R or server.R files directly.  I've looked for a keyboard shortcut for Run App [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) to no avail.

Typing `runApp()` in the Console is a workaround.  Anything better?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is just for a shortcut for Run App, ctrl + shift + enter (on windows) works in server.R, ui.R, and app.R files.

Edit: In RStudio you can also use ctrl+f9 and ctrl+f10 to navigate across open tabs and then use ctrl+shift+enter to execute.

Comment: It does work with the files you mention - unfortunately I rarely work on these as the app is modular.

Comment: You might edit your question then since I think it was misleading. Do you use RStudio?